# Get exception name from set_exception_handler function

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have a couple of exception ex:

```
fooException extends Exception{}
barException extends Exception{}
tarException extends Exception{}
```

here is the exception handler

```
 set_exception_handler('get_exceptions');

  function get_exceptions($msg){
    # how to get the exception name here like
    # fooException barException
  }
```

example errors

```
 if(0){
    throw new fooException;  
 }

 if(!1){
   throw new barException;  
 }
```

Now, inside the `get_exceptions` function I am trying but unable to get what exception type that is being thrown, instead of the the message, code and the whole data. just the name of the class, like `fooException` or `barException` is there anyway to get only the name of the triggered exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$exceptionClass = get_class($msg);
```

Comment: Nope. I tried but didn't do it. Plus, you are asking for class name whereas I am asking for the exception name

Comment: Well, define "exception name" then. What is it? In your question you want "just the name of the class, like fooException or barException". These definetly can be obtained by using get_class()

Comment: Well, I tried that way and I am telling you. It echos nothing at all